# Did we just lose a mod?

Tags: discussion, moderators

A quick look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators would suggest that we're at four mods rather than the usual complement of five.

[image]

**Anything to report?**

Comment: Is Thaddeus also stepping down?

Comment: @fez - I'm not certain. We're approaching the [one year anniversary of the last time he interacted with the site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus-howze?tab=activity&sort=all&page=2) though.

Comment: A [certain user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin) no longer has a diamond.

Comment: @DavidW - His profile hasn't changed.

Comment: I ... have no idea. Whatever happened, nobody's informed the mod team about it. Please hold off on speculation until we get word from Kevin or the CM team.

Comment: @Randal'Thor if this is on purpose (and not some weird mistake), it has happened today at some point, to give an idea of timescale.

Comment: Also coming up on [the anniversary of the last time he interacted with the site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin?tab=activity).

Comment: Just to allay any worries here: we (mods) have made contact with the SE Community Team and discussion is ongoing. ASR has added the [meta-tag:status-review] tag to this meta post, so we should get an official response here from an employee with as much info as can be public, although probably not today.

Comment: FWIW he's no longer on mod on [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) either.

Comment: @fez - It looks like the answer is yes.

Answer (score 28):

**Yes**
Community Managers reach out to moderators when they have been [inactive for more than six months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337431/what-is-the-process-regarding-moderator-inactivity-removals/338006#338006). Moderators have the option to either resume moderating or let us know that they would like to step away from moderating responsibilities and we then notify the other moderators. In this particular instance I was pulled into something pressing before I had a chance to reach out to the moderators to give them a heads up, which is why there was a delay. I apologize for that.

When moderators step down, the CMs chat with the remaining moderators around their needs for additional moderators to get an idea of when in the future an election may be held.

Comment: Hi Rosie! For everyone's information, Rosie reached out to speak to us Mods before posting, so everyone should now be up to date (including the community).