# Did we just lose *another* moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

A quick look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators would suggest that we're at three mods rather than the usual complement of <s>[five](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/did-we-just-lose-a-mod)</s> four.

[image]

**Anything to report?**

Comment: *"To lose one moderator may be regarded as a misfortune. to lose two looks like carelessness."*

Comment: We were aware this time, just not quick enough in announcing it (we have other things to announce as well). Stand by stackizens...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Ooh. Other announcements? We're all ears...

Comment: @valorum, that's a terrifying mental image. I may have to go lie down before making any announcements.

Comment: In case of some users, a more appropriate image is "all mouths" (or fingers on keyboard?)

Answer (score 16):

**Yes.**

In the last couple of weeks, Stack Exchange staff reached out to two of our site's moderators who [hadn't done anything on the site for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338006/278659). I don't know exactly what happened in those communications, since they were off-site and private between CMs and those individual moderators, but the end result is the removal of the two inactive moderators.

As I [mentioned before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/did-we-just-lose-a-mod#comment46921_13335), the remaining mods were caught off-guard the first time this happened, since [Rosie](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/137155/rosie) was called AFK in the time between removing Kevin's diamond and dropping a message into our mod chat. We *were* informed the second time, but we neglected to post anything to inform the community. I apologise on behalf of the remaining mod team for this omission: we *should* keep you informed when things like this happen, and it's not a good look for missing moderators to be announced by "what just happened?" posts from community members. Sorry about that.